# Bootstrap 4 - реализация макета - возможности Bootstrap

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Как можно сверстать такой макет как на рисунке?
Поля: поле1-поле6 выводятся через цикл. Их может быть сколько угодно.
При декстопной версии таблица должна выглядеть как на верхнем рисунке, а при уменьшении с 767 должна выглядеть как нижний рисунок.
Все это находится внутри `.container-fluid`.
Можно ли такое реализовать не по отдельности, т.е. в мобильной версии прячем первый вид, а  второй показываем и наоборот?

[image: Макет]

Comment: А как Вы сами думаете - можно без подмены реализовать таблицы с абсолютно разной структурой?

Comment: Ну чисто теоретически - можно генерировать таблицу с помощью js в зависимости от разрешения

Comment: Если, например, на декстопе заголовки (первую строку) сделать отдельной таблицой, она пускай в мобильной версии прячется. Потом отдельно идут типа заголовок1-поле1, заголовок2-поле2 и.т.д., (в цикле) только в этой таблице прячутся на декстопе все заголовки, как-то типа такого можно реализовать?

Comment: можно. Реализуйте